# How to convert a values like 1225002 to 1.2M in a column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have got a dataframe using instagramy. The dataframe consists of columns like Usernames, Followers, Following, Posts.

The dataframe looks like this

```
         Usernames  Followers  Following  Posts
0          A        1225002       1675   5647
1          B        11565253        998  12806
2          C         433688        895    994
3          D        7600455         31  15295
4          E           6706         33    478
5          F           1425        162     12
.          .            .           .       .
.          .            .           .       .
n          n           n            n       n
```

What I want to do is simply convert the values of followers from  `1225002` to `1.2M`
`11565253` to `11.5M`
So that the final dataframe will look like this

```
         Usernames  Followers  Following  Posts
0          A        1.2M       1675   5647
1          B        11.5M        998  12806
2          C         433K        895    994
3          D        7.6M         31  15295
4          E           6706         33    478
5          F           1425        162     12
.          .            .           .       .
.          .            .           .       .
n          n           n            n       n
```

I have tried to use numpy and pandas for converting the absolute numbers to a numerical string like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542176/how-to-convert-numeric-strings-such-as-200-13k-and-1-2m-to-integer-using-pandas) but I do not know the correct way of doing that. How can I do it? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and `lambda` along with `formatted string`:

```py
df['Followers'].apply(lambda x: f'{x/1000000:.1f}M' if x/1000000>=1 else f'{int(x/1000)}K' if x/10000>=1 else f'{x}')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
0     1.2M
1    11.6M
2     433K
3     7.6M
4     6706
5     1425
Name: Followers, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, this worked fine! never thought this could be done by using apply()

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to do this.Replace every thousands place by the suffix 'K' or 'M', likewise:

```
def words(num):
    thousands = 0
    while num >= 1000:
        thousands += 1
        num /= 1000
    return '%s%s' % (str(int(num)), ['', 'K', 'M'][thousands])

df['Followers'].apply(lambda num: words(num))
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, this works just fine

Comment: `.0f` automatically rounds off the value I guess.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Hi thank you so much for pointing that out, didn't notice that. I've fixed it.