# Pandas format large numbers

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
   product    price 
0     a       100000     
1     b       2000000     
2     c       30000000000
```

and I would like to convert the price column to the following format

```
   product    price 
0     a       100K     
1     b       2M     
2     c       30B
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a values like 1225002 to 1.2M in a column using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556201/how-to-convert-a-values-like-1225002-to-1-2m-in-a-column-using-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

Extending the answer from [how-to-convert-a-values-like-1225002-to-1-2m-in-a-column-using-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556201/how-to-convert-a-values-like-1225002-to-1-2m-in-a-column-using-pandas) ,
You can use `apply` alongwith `lambda` and `f-string` to get the required output

```py
df['price']=df['price'].apply(lambda x: f'{x//1000000000}B' if x/1000000000>=1 else f'{x//1000000}M' if x/1000000>=1 else f'{int(x//1000)}K' if x/10000>=1 else f'{x}')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
    product price
0      a    100K
1      b    2M
2      c    30B
```

Answer (score 0):

From what my understanding we can just cover the number with accounting format, which is easy for you to read and also still keep the accuracy

```
df['price'].map('{:,}'.format)
0           100,000
1         2,000,000
2    30,000,000,000
Name: price, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [formatting long numbers as strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579310/formatting-long-numbers-as-strings-in-python/45846841)

```
def human_format(num):
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000.0
    # add more suffixes if you need them
    return '%.2f%s' % (num, ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P'][magnitude])
df['price'] = df['price'].apply(human_format)
```