# How to update a column value to millions of dollars: PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column **earnings** in int form, and want to convert to millions of dollars. At the moment i'm getting

> KeyError on 'earnings'

using below formula, How do i fix this.

```
biopics = biopics['earnings'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(('$', format(int(x), ','))) if not '$' in x else x)
```

Comment: Can you show us your Dataframe or error is reflected may be your Dataframe does not contain column named earnings

Comment: This may mean that your dataframe does not contain the "earnings" column. Check your dataframe, your spelling etc...

Comment: See if this can help [Convert 1225002 to 1.2m in pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556201/how-to-convert-a-values-like-1225002-to-1-2m-in-a-column-using-pandas/67556302#67556302)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To convert int to dollar currency format, try doing this:

```
biopics['earnings'] = biopics['earnings'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(('$', format(int(x), ','))) if not '$' in str(x) else x)
```

This will convert 10000 to $10,000

2. To convert it to M, K dollar format:

```
biopics['earnings'] = biopics['earnings'].apply(lambda x: f'${x/1000000:.1f}M' if x/1000000>=1 else f'${int(x/1000)}K' if x/10000>=1 else f'${x}')
```

This will convert 10000000 to $10M and 10000 to $10K